# What is the folded size of ORI AR18 or ORI CR87?

Tags: folding-bicycle

I'm assuming ORI AR18 and ORI CR87 use the same frame design and size. I couldn't find any specs on these bikes about its folded dimension.

http://www.oribikes.com/ori/upload/download/2012%20Catalogue.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a footnote on page 3 of the PDF brochure you linked:

- Approximate unfolded size L:1430 W:550 H:1000 Wheelbase:980 BB height:300 (mm) mm mm
- Approximate folded size L:690 W:310 H:630 Volume:0.134 (mm) m
- Ori is designed and tested for use by riders weighing up to 100kg

Comment: Good detective work :)